# Are "worth" and "value" interchangeable?

Tags: meaning, differences

Say I was to describe someone (or something) as:

> "Having a lot of value".

Could I also say:

> "Having a lot of worth"

and mean the same thing?

---

Edit, another example:

> "This document has value"

vs

> "This document has worth"

Comment: Look here: http://wikidiff.com/value/worth HTH

Comment: Yes! take a look at this : http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/valueless-vs-worthless.1922829/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the words *worth* and *value* are not directly interchangeable.

Consider the following phrases:

> - having a lot of value
> - they value your time
> - it was worth it

Each of the above phrases is [idiomatic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idiomatic). But if you substitute *worth* and *value* for each other, you get

> - *having a lot of worth
> - *they worth your time
> - *it was value it

which are *not* idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

"Value" means it can be assigned a value -- ie, (possibly figuratively) you can exchange it for money or some other fungible good.  "Worth" means that it serves a useful function (if only to make you feel good).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they are.

Mirriam Webster
Simple Definition of worth. : an amount of something that has a specified value, that lasts for a specified length of time, etc. : the amount of money that something is worth. : usefulness or importance.